# Email: DKIM Fails with S/MIME Signature

Tags: dkim, smime, postfix-mta

We have the following Mail Flow in our Company.

Exchange => ASSP => Postfix (DKIM Applies here) => CiperMail (S/MIME Applies here) => Internet

Now I face a problem, that as soon as I sign a Mail with S/MIME (Not encrypt - only sign), the DKIM Signature fails.

Why is that ? Any Idea, how to achieve having DKIM and S/MIME?

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 1):

1) THE PROBLEM

By applying S/MIME after DKIM you're changing the 'DKIMed' mail. Thus invalidating the hash.

2) THE SOLUTION

It should be done the other way round.

3) THE CLARIFICATION OF THE SOLUTION

The other way round means apply S/MIME first and then DKIM.

Comment: You can pass on the information without sounding arrogant. I'd recommend editing your answer here to make it more friendly. As you can already see, part of it has already been removed.

Comment: My answer has a 'history'. My intial post was friendly and did not contain any uppercase but has been deleted. Reason: 'This does not provide an answer to the question'. So I added the upercase headings and the explanation what 'the other way round' means. This made the technically same anwer 'sufficient'.

Comment: Don't confuse "not an answer" with "unclear explanation". If it was flagged, it was done by multiple reviewers (not one single person, or the OP).

Comment: This is confusing. You wrote that the problem was that S/MIMe was applied after DKIM and the the solution is to apply DKIM before S/MIME. How is that any different?

Comment: You're right, point 3 *was* confusing (I've edited the entry). S/MIME first and DKIM after that is right.